# Private Bitbucket repository not creating packages in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I am trying to generate package in Jenkins with poll SCM (* * * * *) mechanism.
If I keep my repository public, and if I commit any changes from visual studio to bitbucket, It is creating packages in Jenkins (**Still I need to click on Build Now option in Jenkins**).

If I make my repository private, and if I commit any changes from visual studio to bitbucket, It's giving me timeout error in build console and url not able to access in configuration.

Public repository (Working),
[image: public]

Private repository (Not working),
[image: private]

What changes I need to make in configuration to make it work.

Comment: You masked the password in the url but it is there in the error msg make sure mask in all the places.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you git url. Since you are passing the credentials in the url itself you have to URL encode the username and the password.

But since you are configuring the credentials in the credentials section you can remove the username and password from the url Jenkins's git client will take care of passing the credentials.

Comment: Tried second way, But no luck. 
Do I have to generate SSH key on my system and need to configure in bit bucket?